# Interpret Timestamp value from Binance in R

Tags: r, api, datetime, timestamp, binance

I am working with [Binance APIs](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) in R. It is mentioned that all the time and timestamps are in milliseconds. And when I retrieve the list of orders in R by GET command from httr package, I get the time in the following format:-

```
[1] 1.530289e+12 1.530289e+12 1.530289e+12 1.530290e+12 1.530290e+12
```

or

`[1] 1530289083143 1530289248074 1530289249920 1530290497231 1530290498147`

Could you kindly tell me how to interpret it in either the real time or datetime format such as: 2018-6-29 16:24:35.555

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`as.POSIXct()` counts the number of seconds from the epoch (the 1st of January 1970), but the response that you get from Binance is in milliseconds. So once you have requested the timestamp, you have to convert it from milliseconds to seconds to change it into a datetime format.

I break it down below. The function `getTimestamp()` simply requests the timestamp from Binance.

```
timestamp_request <- getTimestamp()

timestamp <- as.numeric(timestamp_request) / 1000

date_time <- as.POSIXct(timestamp, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")

print(timestamp_request)

print(timestamp)

print(date_time)
```

Printing out the results of each step,

```
> print(timestamp_request)
[1] "1648640978297"
> 
> print(timestamp)
[1] 1648640978
> 
> print(date_time)
[1] "2022-03-30 11:32:49 GMT"
```

Answer (score -1):

That will give you the date, time etc. with seconds not the milliseconds.
If you nee to know the milliseconds you will have to change a little:

```
Binance_Time_Stamp_Converted = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(Binance_Time_Stamp/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
pprint.pprint (Binance_Time_Stamp_Converted)
```